# LibreOffice prints everything half size

Tags: printing, libreoffice

Ever since I printed a document from Evince in landscape orientation, LibreOffice Calc / Writer refuses to print anything correctly.  It is scaling everything by 0.5x and rotating it.  To get the same effect, go to print -> page layout tab -> pages per sheet = 2.  However, I don't want 2.  I want 1.

I have wizzed through all of the printing options a few times but can't get to the bottom of this.  I've restarted my printer and computer several times.  I have done `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*` and reinstalled again.  Still it will not print full size.

(Of course I have checked that the page settings are set to A4 and portrait.)

Update: this problem is specific to one printer only, to printing from within LibreOffice (Calc, Writer).  With other printers / programs I have no problems.

Comment: What happens if you print from other applications (Browser, LibreOffice Writer, Gnumeric, gedit or anything else)? Which ubuntu version are you using? 12.04?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  All other applications are fine.  (For the moment I am doing export to pdf and then printing from evince = works.)  I can confirm this is not just Calc - Writer is also doing the same.

Comment: I'm at a loss to fix this!  I have done sudo apt-get purge libreoffice* and reinstalled, and printed a brand new document.  It still prints everything half size.  This time a two page landscape document gets printed to fit exactly onto one A4 portrait piece of paper :-/

Comment: make sure you're doing everything as specified here: http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_Page_Orientation_Landscape_or_Portrait.

Comment: This is an obvious one but I'll post it in the interest of being thorough: `Print/Page Layout(tab)/Pages per sheet` should be set to **1**.

Comment: I have tried printing with another printer (without changing any settings from within LibreOffice) and found it to be working.  It is therefore a printer-specific problem.  However, it's just LibreOffice and not other programs.

Comment: @green7 Thanks for the suggestion.  Given that it is printing correctly with one printer but incorrectly with my default printer (without changing ANY document options), my guess is that it can't be related to anything on the "Changing Page Orientation" page.

Comment: Can you delete `~/.config/evince` (copy to your desktop if you want a backup) and try again? I suspect this has more to do with evince than LibreOffice or the printer. Open your home folder in Nautilus and press Ctrl + H to show hidden files which will reveal the .config folder.

Comment: @TomBrossman Sorry, I read this too late to try it.  Since deleting the printer and re-installing it, the problem has gone away.

Comment: Okay, glad it is fixed anyhow. I'll flag this for closure as 'too localized' since the problem was temporary.

Comment: @TomBrossman I am still new to stack exchange.  Was this the right place to ask the question in the first place, or are the ubuntu forums more appropriate?  Another, unrelated question: do I need to 'mention' you (as I have been doing in my replies to your comments) for you to get notified of my comments?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It's no problem at all. The [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) covers this but basically since the problem went away it is impossible to tell if any of the answers would have helped. This invalidates the question, the correct answer cannot be determined. You can ask it again if it repeats. Also, doing the @ mentions *is* necessary to get someone's attention, unless you are posting a comment in a question or answer that user authored, in which case they are automatically notified. Hope that helps? If not, [try the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: deleted offending printer and reinstalled.  Now everything is now working OK.

I still have no idea what went wrong though...

Comment: Good idea : I had suddenly  the same problem in latest  Libreoffice  from  xubuntu 16.04: deleting/recreating  printer  solved . Not so  evident as other software  printing were  ok .

Comment: It's amazing that the same problem and solution from 2012 are still relevant!

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and tried a lot of solutions for that and found only one that works. To print document in landscape you have to create Lanscape style.

Go to `Format` -  `Styles and Formatting`

Then go to tab `Page Styles`. Right click and select `New`.

Create new style, (named for example "Landscape"), under Page tab select paper format and most important **Landscape** orientation. 
Turn off/on Header and footer by will. 
Save it and activate Page Style by double-click on it (in my case Landscape). 
File Print.. and voila! 
To go back to regular portrait print just double-click **Default** Page Style under Styles and Formatting.

Comment: Hi @alen-t, thanks for the answer.  But I'm not trying to print landscape!